# How to parse YAML file and create child-objects from parent struct (inheritance)

Tags: go, inheritance, yaml

let‘s assume that I have the following structs:

```
type CarShop struct {
  Cars []*Car
}

type Car struct {
  ID string `yaml:“id“`
}

type BMW struct {
  Car
  A string `yaml:“a“`
}

type Mercedes struct {
  Car
  B string `yaml:“b“
}
```

I would like to parse the following string:

```
- BMW:
    id: „BMW“
    a: „a“
- Mercedes:
    id: „Mercedes“
    b: „b“
```

What do I have to do to dynamically create BMW and Mercedes objects parsing this string? Is that even possible using Go and go-yaml?

Comment: Have you tried implementing the Unmarshaler interface with Car?

Comment: Thx for your suggestion! I think the comment by flyx illustrates this implementation very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your types are wrong, Go doesn't have inheritance. You cannot store a value of type `*Mercedes` or `*BMW` into an array of type `[]*Car`; both types just *include* a `Car` value as a mixin. To do what you want to do, you have to change your `Car` type into an interface.

Now for the YAML part: You can store a part of your YAML structure inside an object of type `yaml.Node` and deserialize that later. You can implement a custom unmarshaler by implementing `UnmarshalYAML` (from the `yaml.Unmarshaler` interface). So what we're gonna do is to implement a custom unmarshaler for `CarShop` that deserializes the surrounding structure into a list containing mappings from car type to `yaml.Node` (the values for that type), and then depending on the given car types, deserialize each node into the proper type. Here's how it looks:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type CarShop struct {
    Cars []Car
}

type Car interface {
    ID() string
}

type BMW struct {
    IDVal string `yaml:"id"`
    A     string `yaml:"a"`
}

func (bmw *BMW) ID() string {
    return bmw.IDVal
}

type Mercedes struct {
    IDVal string `yaml:"id"`
    B     string `yaml:"b"`
}

func (merc *Mercedes) ID() string {
    return merc.IDVal
}

type tmpCarShop []map[string]yaml.Node

func (cs *CarShop) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
    var tmp tmpCarShop
    if err := value.Decode(&tmp); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    cars := make([]Car, 0, len(tmp))
    for i := range tmp {
        for kind, raw := range tmp[i] {
            switch kind {
            case "Mercedes":
                m := &Mercedes{}
                if err := raw.Decode(m); err != nil {
                    return err
                }
                cars = append(cars, m)
            case "BMW":
                b := &BMW{}
                if err := raw.Decode(b); err != nil {
                    return err
                }
                cars = append(cars, b)
            default:
                return errors.New("unknown car type: " + kind)
            }
        }
    }
    cs.Cars = cars
    return nil
}

func main() {
    input := []byte(`
- BMW:
    id: "BMW"
    a: "a"
- Mercedes:
    id: "Mercedes"
    b: "b"
`)

    var shop CarShop
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(input, &shop); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for i := range shop.Cars {
        fmt.Printf("ID: %s\n", shop.Cars[i].ID())
        switch c := shop.Cars[i].(type) {
        case *Mercedes:
            fmt.Printf("Type: Mercedes\nA: %s\n", c.B)
        case *BMW:
            fmt.Printf("Type: BMW\nB: %s\n", c.A)
        }
        fmt.Println("---")
    }
}
```